# SELECT words composed only by specified letters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to select words composed ONLY by specified letters.

For example given the sequence 'by' would be selected words that contains zero or more 'b' or zero and more 'y'.

Allowed: 'b', 'y', 'byb', 'bbyy', 'byyybb', 'yy' and so on.
NOT allowed: 'by**e**', 'b**a**by'

A kind of super-anagrams.

This is part of a Java application, so if is not possible to do this in a query I'll find a solution in Java

Comment: Try regular expression match: `[letters]+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the regular expressions

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col REGEXP '^[by]{0,}$'
```

The sequence **'by'** can be changed by any wished sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '%b%' OR col LIKE '%y%'
```

Where tbl is the table name in MySQL and col is the column name within the table.

Comment: Nope it would return words that contains the given letters

Comment: @Vitasalato your question seems to ask for exactly that. Perhaps you need to clarify it.

Comment: @Vitasalato I see your meaning now. I think the best way to do what you need would be to use Regular Expressions, and unfortunately there's no support for RegEx in MS SQL.

If you're using MySQL, then you can refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html on how to build a regular expression into your query, however it looks like the operator only tells you if there's a match and doesn't seem to return the actual data. I've not used RegEx directly in MySQL before, so I'm afraid I don't have much to add beyond the link. 

It may be better to just use RegEx from your app.